# How to configure nlog.config to include asp.net core 2 web api request custom header information?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I have a simple asp.net core web api application (using the default web api template in Visual Studio 2017) using nlog for logging message to console in JSON format.

- ASP.NET Core 2: 2.0.5
- NLog version: 4.5.0-rc07
- NLog.Web.AspNetCore:
  4.5.0-rc03

Here is the NLog configuration file:

```xml
 <!-- the targets to write to -->
 <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="console_log" >
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="ts" layout="${date}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        **<attribute name="all-events" layout="${all-event-properties}"/>
        <attribute name="tid" layout="${aspnet-request:header=tid}"/>**
        <attribute name="cn" layout="${callsite}"/>
        <attribute name="msg" layout="${message}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console_log" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

In Startup.cs, the Configure method contains the following two lines:

```
        env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
```

I got the JSON format log message output to console. However, I was not able to receive the tid which is a custom header in the HTTP request header.

How can I extract the HTTP request header and output it to the console?

I appreciate your comments/answers/guidance. Thank you.

Comment: The problem was missing the NLog.Web.AspNetCore extensions in the nlog.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${aspnet-request}` depends on `HttpContextAccessor`. Please update your code to use `UseNLog` on IWebHostBuilder (See program.cs in this example)

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs

`UseNLog` will automatically register `HttpContextAccessor` (Remember to remove any usage of `ConfigureNLog` or `AddNLog`, but only use `UseNLog` and `LogManager.LoadConfiguration` as shown in above example)

Comment: I followed the URL link to setup the NLog. Thank you. However, my main challenge is how to configure the nlog.config entry to show the custom header without explicitly extracting the information in the request processing pipeline and setting the logging context if it is possible. If it is possible, is the following line in the nlog.config correct?

<attribute name="tid" layout="${aspnet-request:header=tid}"/>

Comment: @PaulS `UseNLog` will give access to `HttpContextAccessor`, that will give access to HttpRequest.Headers, which can be logged using `${aspnet-request:header=tid}`. But I'm no expert, in your solution. It sounds like you have banged something random together that doesn't match how the Wiki recommends. Maybe you need to check the NLog internal logger for any warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestion on checking the NLog internal logger. I missed the following in the nlog.config. <extensions> <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/></extensions>

Answer (score 0):

you could use an `ActionFilterAttribute` like this:

```
public class HttpHeadersLogger : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.Append(request.RequestType + " " + request.Url + "\n");

        var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, null, null);
        var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.Headers.ToString());

        foreach (string key in parsed)
        {
            // Search for 'tid' header here to only log these one
            logEventInfo.Properties.Add(key, parsed[key]);
        }

        _log.Log(logEventInfo);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

In this example, all the headers are being logged, you should filter that if you only want the 'tid' one.
This will use the NLog layout expression, by using the object `LogEventInfo` to perform the logging operation.